# WCF client Thread was being aborted

Tags: multithreading, wcf, exception

I have the following problem:

We have a Web server (windows server 2003 with IIS 6) hosting a WS-HttpBinding WCF service, .NET 3.5 (throttling is set accordingly to MS documentation).

We have an ASPX page also hosted in IIS calling that WCF service (Don't ask why).

In production, we **sometimes** get an exception for the WCF client: Thread was being aborted.

What could possibly be the reason for this happening?

(We are closing the connections to the server for sure)

Thanks

Comment: did you try to enable wcf tracing? Can you post your error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we found out why this was happening, apparently there was a mediating ASMX web service with a low executionTimeout (in httpRuntime element) that was aborting the WCF client.